# Usage before initialization of const member, is this expected behaviour of gcc and clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

Consider the following snippet. Class `test` has a const member `a` and a member function `fun` which returns `a`. An initialization list is used to to initialize `a` in the constructor. However in the initialization list a lambda is used to initialize `a` with the returned value of fun. This leads to different behaviors of clang and gcc at compile and runtime, depending on the optimization level. Below the snippet and the different outputs at compile and runtime are listed. Is this expected behavior of gcc and clang?

```
#include <iostream>

class test{
    public:
    const int a;

    test(): a([this](){return fun();}()) {}

    int fun()
    {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto t = test();
    std::cout << t.a << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Compiletime:

```
clang++-5.0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Weverything

lambda_in_initializer_list.cpp:7:15: warning: lambda expressions are incompatible with C++98
      [-Wc++98-compat]
    test(): a([this](){return fun();}()) {}
              ^
warning: 'auto' type specifier is incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
lambda_in_initializer_list.cpp:17:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is incompatible with C++98
      [-Wc++98-compat]
    auto t = test();
    ^~~~
3 warnings generated.
```

---

```
clang++-5.0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Weverything -O1

lambda_in_initializer_list.cpp:7:15: warning: lambda expressions are incompatible with C++98
      [-Wc++98-compat]
    test(): a([this](){return fun();}()) {}
              ^
warning: 'auto' type specifier is incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
lambda_in_initializer_list.cpp:17:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is incompatible with C++98
      [-Wc++98-compat]
    auto t = test();
    ^~~~
```

---

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic

No output
```

---

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O1

lambda_in_initializer_list.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
lambda_in_initializer_list.cpp:18:20: warning: ‘t.test::a’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << t.a << '\n';
                  ~~^
```

Runtime:

```
clang++-5.0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Weverything

0
```

---

```
clang++-5.0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Weverything -O1

4196112
```

---

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic

Non deterministic output.
```

---

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O1

0
```

Comment: What deterministic value you would have expected?

Comment: You have undefined behavior.  All results are valid

Comment: Of course this is not the correct way of initializing the variable. I would expect clang to warn me and gcc to warn me not only when optimization is turned on. I would also expect the program to print the same value regardless of the optimization level.

Comment: Welcome to UB land.  The compiler doesn't have to tell you about it and different implementations can do different things.  You can even get different things from each run of the same binary.

Comment: -Weverything is not a good idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't quite understood a question, but it seems like you are actually asking 'why gcc didn't warn you until you turned up optimization'.

This is a known thing. Detecting undefined behavior in complex cases requires quite a lot of efforts on compiler side, and often is only done when you are optimizing code (since compiler is doing a lot of work anyways). Just something to keep in mind when you are dealing with real life-compilers.